# Intermittent Javascript animation conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am experiencing a problem with some Javascript - please see my site and code here - http://bit.ly/M1YCV7.

The page opens with a logo and nav menu in the centre. When you click a nav link, the logo moves up and the page content box should appear below it. The animation is perfect for all links apart from the first (which in this case is ABOUT), where it sometimes only triggers the logo animation and leaves the content hidden.

Is there anything I can do to ensure it does everything at the same time? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contentslider library expects an element with the id "pagination-settings" on init, and when it doesn't find one, it crashes, throwing an exception. Not sure why the rest of the library still works, though.

Comment: That is great, thanks very much - all working fine now I have put the div back in.

Answer (score 0):

try lunching your script on onload event instead of onready.
i think problem originates from running code before complete load of page.
in general this type of scripts (involving jquery animation) must wait for page to load completly , then starts the animation.event better you can show a waiting before complete load of the page.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it appears I gutted the code too much and got rid of an essential pagination div.